# Script that selects a random number from a specific range on Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

It is my first time using JavaScript on Google Sheets and I want to be able to get a number from a given range (for example, if the range has the values 1, 7, 21, 41 and 52, the script must select any of these numbers).

There are four possible ranges based on the value of a specific cell ("F3"). For instance, if cell F3 = "CTA" then pick a number from Range1, but if cell F3 = "Value Proposition", then pick a random number from Range2.

The logical sequence would be:

```
function GenerateNumber() {
 if (F3 === "CTA") {
  Pick any number between Range(A1:A200)}
    else if (F3 === "Value Proposition") {
        Pick any number between Range(B1:B200) }
            else if (F3 === "Introduction") {
                Pick any number between Range(C1:C200) }
                    else if (F3 === "Benefit Statement") {
                        Pick any number between Range(D1:D200) }
                            else { "There is no data" } }
```

I hope I was clear. Do not hesitate in asking me for more info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into `getRange().getValues()` and `Math.random`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to get an integer random number using random() Method, then use it to define the index of the row where you collect the data. The index of the column will be defined by if-else statement.

Please have a look at the following:

```js
function GenerateNumber() {
  var spreadsheet, sheet, DataNumber, Index
  
  // Reference to the spreadsheet
  spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  
  // Defines the number of data in your range (based on your spreadsheet columns A, B and C)
  DataNumber = sheet.getLastRow()
  
  // Return a integer random number between 1 and the number of your data
  Index = Math.floor((Math.random() * DataNumber) + 1)

  if (sheet.getRange("E2").getValue() === "Case 1") {
    // Uses the integer random number to define the row where you want to extract the data
    // Reports the extracted data in F2 cell
    sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(sheet.getRange("A" + Index).getValue())  
    
  } else if (sheet.getRange("E2").getValue() === "Case 2") {
    
    sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(sheet.getRange("B" + Index).getValue())
    
  } else if (sheet.getRange("E2").getValue() === "Case 3") {
    
    sheet.getRange("F2").setValue(sheet.getRange("C" + Index).getValue())
    
  } else {
    
    sheet.getRange("F2").setValue("There is no data")
    
  }
}
```

[This is a screenshot of my spreadheet file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4UyC.png)